# ReactPHP memory problem with keep-alive connections

Tags: php, rest, keep-alive, reactphp, fastroute

I have a API Rest developed with ReactPHP and FastRoute. If I call it from a web interfaz with header "Connection: keep-alive" the memory starts to increase until memory crash. I tried to change the header to "Connection: close" and there are not memory leaks.

Do you know why is this happening?
Can I disable keep-alive in my ReactPHP server?

Thanks

This is the code of my server

```
$server = new Server($loop, new ErrorHandler(), new JsonRequestDecoder(), new CorsMiddleware([
    'allow_origin' => [
        '*',
        'http://localhost:3000'
    ],
    'allow_methods'     => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
    'allow_headers'     => ['DNT','X-Custom-Header','Keep-Alive','User-Agent','X-Requested-With','If-Modified-Since','Cache-Control','Content-Type','Content-Range','Range'],
    'expose_headers'    => ['DNT','X-Custom-Header','Keep-Alive','User-Agent','X-Requested-With','If-Modified-Since','Cache-Control','Content-Type','Content-Range','Range']
 
]), new Router($routes));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReactPHP maintainer here.

This got also reported in https://github.com/reactphp/http/issues/514 in our [ReactPHP HTTP component](https://github.com/reactphp/http) and we fixed this just a few days ago through https://github.com/reactphp/http/pull/515. Like you said above, this only occurs when using persistent connections (keep-alive), the memory grew because the connection close handler was not being cleaned up properly for each request.

We're currently focusing on a new reactphp/http `v1.10.0` which is planned to be released around next week and will contain the fix for this. Once released you can install the new version and shouldn't encounter this issue anymore.